# Newly Created Certificate is Already Expired on XCode

Tags: xcode, cordova, xcodebuild

i'm trying to upload an app for days, had to move it from one mac to another, tried everthing on the internet to export the old certificate and private key to the new mac, but it just doesn't work. I suspect it's because of "revokate certificate" option on xcode. Now i'm trying to do it by myself with the information that is presented. I saw the following:

[image: )]

When i use this to create a certificate
(distribuition or development), i noticed that the certificate that was created, is already expired, as the image below demonstrates. Why is this happening? Thanks in advance!

[image]